# Facebook og:image not defined

Tags: facebook

I'm running a Facebook contest on my business page and having issues with the image that shows up when I share the URL (`https://trinitytrainingreferafriend.shortstack.com/2w4fVC`).

I've tried using the debugger tool which tells me:

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image “https://d2xcq4qphg1ge9.cloudfront.net/assets/380869/2850001/original_Screen_Shot_2015-08-01_at_11.34.10_PM.png?1438486501” will be used instead.

The weird thing being, scrolling down (highlighted in red in attachment), the correct graphic is displayed.

Comment: You example URL only responds with a 404 now.